# Installing Ubuntu and PostgreSQL database on different drives

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, system-installation, postgresql

I just received a new root server ([this one](https://www.hetzner.de/de/hosting/produkte_rootserver/px121ssd)) with the following drives:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 480 Gb
Disk /dev/sdb: 480 Gb
Disk /dev/sdc: 240 Gb
```

Plus the 240Gb SSD.

Both `sda` and `sdb` are set up on RAID-1 and what I want to do is setup Ubuntu 14.04 on the smallest drive (`sdc: 280 Gb`) and a PostgreSQL database on one of the other drives configured in RAID.

The server is started in rescue mode on Debian 7.0 Wheezy. My interface shows up like this:

```
root@rescue ~ #
```

I would like to know, from the rescue mode, how can I install Ubuntu only on the drive that I want and then exit the rescue mode?

For setting up `postgres` I already found a couple of tutorials;

- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/103261/point-postgresql-on-ubuntu-to-a-new-datadir
- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/43155/optimum-configuration-for-4-ssd-drives
- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/28926/moving-postgresql-data-to-different-drive

So it will be easy once the initial and most important OS setup is done.

#### The reason I want to do this

In the previous companies I've worked for, whenever there was an issue with the OS and we needed a repair or reinstall it, for safety measures the sys-admin team had to burden with moving all non-OS data into a different drive while the repairs were made.

I found [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/OverSSH), but as it says in the beginning, it may 'break' my system which is exactly what I don't want to do!

I want to make sure I install Ubuntu in the correct drive, from rescue, and boot it afterward from my installed OS, so that I can continue with my PostgreSQL installation on a different drive.

Comment: Can you boot Ubuntu from CD or USB and then run the Ubuntu installer?

Comment: I tried installing the image from a prebuilt script from hetzner: http://wiki.hetzner.de/index.php/Installimage/en    but got an error on DRIVE1, which i commented out along with DRIVE2 (Only left DRIVE3 fo 240Gb open) for it to install ubuntu on it

Comment: Do you have access to, and can you boot from, the USB drive?

Comment: What is the hardware architecture? amd64, i386, ARM, etc?

Comment: Updated in the topic

Comment: Did you email support at hetzner about the errors you got with their script?